# join only one row out of many possible rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i do need help with a query.

Details:
I have 5 million events with ID and EventID and one [datetime] starttime.
The ID-EventID are no unique keys and can happen several times a day.
To every row i might have no matches, one match or even 10.000 matching [datetime] endtimes within the next 5 days.

What i need is only the one endtime which is closest to the starttime.

The query itself is fairly simple but due to the fact, that i have several million events with each a possible of 10.000 hits when only needing one hit. It gets into billions and is not working well any more.

I wrote a set of sample data including a sample result. (see below)

What i need is a query which includes only the one matching row and leaves the rest alone.

```
CREATE TABLE #starts(
    [id] [smallint] NULL,
    [event_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [dt_start] [datetime] NULL
)

INSERT #starts ([id], [event_id], [dt_start]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-01 23:06:22.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #starts ([id], [event_id], [dt_start]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-10 23:42:01.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #starts ([id], [event_id], [dt_start]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-28 02:36:44.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #starts ([id], [event_id], [dt_start]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-29 08:56:17.000' AS DateTime))

CREATE TABLE #ends(
    [id] [smallint] NULL,
    [event_id] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [dt_end] [datetime] NULL
)


INSERT #ends ([id], [event_id], [dt_end]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-01 23:09:32.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #ends ([id], [event_id], [dt_end]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-28 02:40:14.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #ends ([id], [event_id], [dt_end]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-28 08:57:39.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #ends ([id], [event_id], [dt_end]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-05-28 14:09:39.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #ends ([id], [event_id], [dt_end]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-06-01 10:18:18.000' AS DateTime))
INSERT #ends ([id], [event_id], [dt_end]) VALUES (2, N'alpha', CAST(N'2015-06-01 14:42:04.000' AS DateTime))
GO

-- one extra step to clarify
select a.id, a.event_id,dt_start, dt_end 
,row_number() over (partition by a.id, a.event_id,dt_start order by dt_end) as rn
from #starts as a
left join #ends as b
on a.id=b.id
and a.event_id=b.event_id
AND a.dt_start<b.dt_end
and datediff(day,dt_start,dt_end) <=5

-- the result
select * from (
select a.id, a.event_id,dt_start, dt_end 
,row_number() over (partition by a.id, a.event_id,dt_start order by dt_end) as rn
from #starts as a
left join #ends as b
on a.id=b.id
and a.event_id=b.event_id
AND a.dt_start<b.dt_end
and datediff(day,dt_start,dt_end) <=5
) as dummy
where rn=1
```

Thanx for any help you might have.

Comment: Is there any chance you could take a sub sample of the massive table?

Comment: You mean like an insert with 5.000 matching endtimes ?
If so: yes, i could generate such sample, but what would it help and can i add several thousand lines of sql-code in here ?

Comment: If you execute the extra step you see the numbering of the matching rows. In the real table those numbers go easy above thousands for most events without ever beeing needed.
I need a way to join only the number #1 and drop the rest right from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.event_id, a.dt_start, min(b.dt_end)
  FROM #starts AS a
  LEFT JOIN #ends AS b
    ON a.id       = b.id
   AND a.event_id = b.event_id
   AND a.dt_start < b.dt_end
   AND DATEDIFF(day, dt_start, dt_end) <= 5  
 GROUP BY a.id, a.event_id, a.dt_start
```

Comment: Hi Frisbee,

thank you a lot. It is so obvious. I apparently got stuck in my algorithm.
This works quite well. 

But since sometimes several thousand endtime events occur within one hour i had to loop through the date. First searching from 1 Minute, than 30 Minute, than 5 days.

Anyway. It is working now in under 10 Minutes instead of multiple hours.

Thanx again.